# Why are Lua libraries written in C-Code

Tags: c, lua

I have started to do some research about Lua and I got pretty confused about how [embedded](https://www.lua.org/start.html#embedding) Lua works:

It says that

> You'll also need a C or C++ compiler for your program, because the Lua headers and library are written in C.

So that means, that I only need a C/C++ compiler for executing Lua, because the library and headers are written in C. That means that all the libraries I write and/or use are C-Code?

I probably misunderstood that, but for me that would mean:

I write some code in Lua and it gets translated into C-code before it is compiled? Or is there a difference between what I import as library and write as "Lua-Code"?

Comment: Yes, the big important parts of Lua is written in C, like for example the actual compiler and interpreter, as well as some libraries. However, you only need the compiler *once*, to build the compiler, interpreter and the Lua libraries written in C. Once built, you don't need the C compiler anymore.

Comment: I can't answer the question completely, but a lot of languages use C or other such languages for their internal functioning or libraries. Some examples that come to mind are MATLAB and Python.

Comment: While you can theoretically build your own Lua libraries in other languages, you will need to translate the relevant parts of the Lua headers which make up the API. That's most likely more trouble than it's worth..

Comment: If you want to embed LUA in an application written in a different language, you need some library in that language that interacts with LUA directly.  LUA is written in C.  If you are using C#, you should *probably* use a library that is meant to embed LUA in C#.  This will inevitably have some calls at some point that interact with the LUA C code directly.  Same for Java, Python, whatever you are using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those instructions are for embedding Lua into your C or C++ program. In that case, you need to interact with the C API for Lua to run Lua scripts inside your program.

If you want to program in pure Lua, you just need the Lua interpreter `lua`.

Lua scripts are not converted to C before execution.

Comment: Alright, so where is the Lua interpreter when I just need to provide a C compiler to embed my Lua-code? How is the Lua code executed when it is not compiled before but also not transformed to C-code?

Comment: @Rüdiger, The Lua library contains a interpreter for a virtual machine. Lua scripts are compiled to instructions for this VM when scripts are loaded by the Lua library. The command line interpreter is just an interface to the Lua library.

Answer (score 2):

Another one thing to mention: many lua libraries (like `lua-socket`) *are* written on C, so you need compiler to use them.

Why they use C? Because they do things *impossible* in pure lua (e.g, working with internet) due to extreme portable lua nature.

Comment: Thanks for that. That means as soon as I do something network-related it is basically a C-library used there and nothing that I can do in pure lua? Did I get that right?

Comment: @Rüdiger Yes, you get it completely right. Of course, you can build libraries on local machine and copy to host (if same ABI is used (OS+Architecture)).